# How to trigger a function of class via button in view

Tags: django, function, view

I'm setting up an application working with Django and Keras. It takes a lot of time to take my uploaded document, prepare, train and to show my results. That's why I'm trying to split my code into different phases. But I don't know how to trigger a function using my created object before. Do you know how to connect a button to trigger a process via using created object?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without code it will be difficult to help you. Please add it to the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trigger an action from a template view you need to set up an endpoint and use needed class/func there. You can call it with ajax if that's you want.

`path('action/', app.views.action, 'action')`

```
def action(request):
    my_util_class.my_function()
    return HttpResponse('')
```

`<a href="{% url 'app:action' %}">Button</a>`

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I need!